# Make sure password contains at least one character from 3 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, passwords

How do I make sure that the password contains at least one character from each array? I could use do..while, right? What I don't quite understand is what I will need to put in the if statement  inside do...while.

Is do...while the only way to ensure at least one character from each array  is in the final password or are there other ways?

```
 $length = 6;  
 $a1 = str_split('0123456789');  
$a2 = str_split('%^*+~?!');  
$a3 = str_split('abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz');  

$result = ""; //final random password

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){

$values = [$a1,$a2,$a3];
$chosen = array_rand($values);

$result .= $values[$chosen][array_rand($values[$chosen])];
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: The NIST now specifically recommends **against** these sorts of "password complexity" rules as they tend to *harm* security rather than improve it. https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html https://www.nist.gov/blogs/taking-measure/easy-ways-build-better-p5w0rd

Comment: Key bit: "As [this XKCD comic points out](https://xkcd.com/936/), complex password rules actually drive us to create predictable, easy-to-guess passwords (“password1!” anybody?) or find other ways to make things easier on ourselves, e.g., reusing passwords across sites or saving them in spreadsheets or sticky notes. In practice, all those rules had made it easier for the bad guy, and harder—and less secure—for the user."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$length = 6;  
$a1 = str_split('0123456789');  
$a2 = str_split('%^*+~?!');  
$a3 = str_split('abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz');  



$resultArr[] = $a1[array_rand($a1)];
$resultArr[] = $a2[array_rand($a2)];
$resultArr[] = $a3[array_rand($a3)];

for($i = 0; $i < $length-3; $i++){

$values = [$a1,$a2,$a3];
$chosen = array_rand($values);

$resultArr[] = $values[$chosen][array_rand($values[$chosen])];
}
shuffle($resultArr);
$result = implode($resultArr); //final random password
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works :) Would you be willing to explain the logic behind "-3" in the for loop? I see it affects the length, of course, but why is it longer than six if the -3 isn't added?

Comment: You want password length 6. But at the beginning you set first 3 position of array with random values of each source arrays. So you have to set 'for' condition $length -3, because first 3 position of result array is already set. Is it clear now?

Comment: Where you validate the result have at least one value of each array?

Comment: I dont have to validate, because at the beginning I'm adding 1 random value of each source array. So I know that is at least one value of each array.

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the `for` wit ha `do..while` and in the condition check with [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) and a regex pattern that checks if at least one character is in the result:

```
<?php

$length = 6;  
$a1 = str_split('0123456789');  
$a2 = str_split('%^*+~?!');  
$a3 = str_split('abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz');  

$result = ""; //final random password

do {
   for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){

        $values = [$a1,$a2,$a3];
        $chosen = array_rand($values);

        $result .= $values[$chosen][array_rand($values[$chosen])];
    } 

} while(!(preg_match('/^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[%*+?!]).{1,}/', $result)));

echo $result;
```

If the there's no coincidences with the pattern using preg_match, then will return false, in the do..while condition we check if one preg_match is false, if it is, do it again.

Comment: Would appreciate if someone can improve my regex, I know I can use only one preg_match.

Comment: The problem is the OP's architecture - e.g., why even str_split() on all digits when OP can simply preg_match("/\d/", $value) and call it a day? Or str_split() alphas when /[a-z]/i works fine? Also, any special character, if this is true goal of OP, achieved via ctype_punct(). Probably no need for arrays at all

Comment: @DavidPartyka looks like the OP is learning and it's a homework task to learn how to use fors, whiles and arrays.

Comment: agreed, but str_split() in my experience is only useful in very select circumstances - if homework, instructor chose one of the least used array-generating functions ;)

Comment: @DavidPartyka I agree  that those arrays are an extra step that I could definitely live without but , as Troyer said, I am learning how  to manipulate arrays and  how to use loops. I appreciate your advice :)

Answer (score -3):

I made my answer general for any number of arrays.

I would use `preg_match()` for this, but for the question you asked, yes, you need to check each array separately:

```
$user_inputted_password = $_POST['user_inputted_password'];

$length = strlen($user_inputted_password); // user input password - you are capturing this somewhere, right

$a1 = str_split('0123456789');  
$a2 = str_split('%^*+~?!');  
$a3 = str_split('abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz');  

$validate = array();

$result = ""; //final random password

function populate_validation_array($match_num, &$validate) {        
    if (!in_array($match_num, $validate)) {
        $validate[] = $match_num; 
    }
}

$numeric_indexes = array(1, 2, 3);
$index_count = count($numeric_indexes);

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){        
    for($j = 0; $j < $index_count; $j++) {
        $numeric_index = $numeric_indexes[$j];
        if (in_array($user_inputted_password[$i], ${"a" . $numeric_index})) {
            populate_validation_array($numeric_index, $validate);
        }
    }
}

if (count($validate) === $index_count) {
    $values = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $index_count; $i++) {
        $values[] = ${"a" . ($i + 1)};
    }
    $chosen = array_rand($values);
    $result .= $values[$chosen][array_rand($values[$chosen])];
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Holy cow, global variable, dat answer, I start to get, why people hatin on php

Comment: @Eakethet - user_password is input right? I will make it simpler for you to understand

Comment: @Eakethet - look at the code again - $user_inputted_password is a string - $user_inputted_password[$i] takes character at position $i - I use this all the time

Comment: The $i-th position - try it on a string in a loop - echo $x[$i];

Comment: And BTW, when you see that I'm correct about the notation, please remove your downvote

Comment: Why? I won't take it personally - "all feedback is good feedback" ... but yes, my original use of the "global" keyword was lazy - agreed on that